# How to convert a project to maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, jboss, jetty

There's quite a bit of information regarding this, but the main problem is when people are talking about maven, it's like Japanese to me. Basically, I have a project with the following .JAR dependencies. The project is an API that's distributed to hundereds of users. I've been wanting to integrate a Jetty server with the API for awhile for remote-access. However, every attempt I've tried has failed due to not using Maven, as it seems it's `required` to have a MAVEN setup to run Jetty.

Here's a list of my dependencies for my project.

- apache-commons-lang.jar
- apache-commons-logging.jar
- com.google.protobuf-2.4.0.jar
- javax.jar
- javax.validation-1.0.0.GA.jar
- jboss-logging.jar
- jjboss-marshalling.jar
- jetty-all-9.3.0-M1.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar
- org.osgi.core-4.2.0.jar
- servlet-api-2.5jar

Basically, I'm getting a bunch of conflicting information on how to properly set this up so that the .JAR generated can be used as an API. I'm reading information saying that if you set it up one way, the JAR will combine and export without any dependency code, thus causing the application to not run on other devices, and other problems.

I honestly don't care about Maven, I just want to get Jetty working, but it seems like this is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how to run jetty from maven, you leverage the plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>8080</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                    <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                        <port>8443</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
                        <keystore>${project.build.directory}/test-classes/keystore</keystore>
                        <password>wicket</password>
                        <keyPassword>wicket</keyPassword>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

In your pom file.

Comment: You have my request backwards, I want to know how to run Jetty without MAVEN

Comment: OH. You can run jetty through ant like this https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Use_Jetty_with_Ant or you can use it in your actual program through java. https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty

Comment: The second link is what I'm after, however it's not working for me, I've tried a few different times. The error I receive when trying to initialize Jetty is as follows `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler` this is using the Jetty-all and servlet-api jars as explained in the examples

Comment: Is it possible to use Jetty 8? I think they changed how Handlers are made when Jetty 9 came out.

Comment: I'll try and get back to you when I get home from the office, thanks for the help.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono there's no change to `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler` with Jetty 9 vs Jetty 8.  especially with regards to NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: @DejaVuSansMono the updated documentation is at https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt - This is the link that I've followed to get the NoClassDefFound,  It's throwing it on the HelloWorld application.

Comment: This has moved well outside of this particular question. let me revive an old question of yours.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a maven project you need to make your dependencies in you pom.xml so to do it you can use this link http://blog.sedona.fr/2013/07/outil-de-migration-de-dependances-ant-vers-maven/

you can translate the page to understand it's french web site